# Prevent user from editing text file when the program is closed

Tags: c++, windows, data-protection

I need to write a program that handles a simple database. My goal is to simply write all the data in memory into a .txt and then at program start read it all in. I want to be able to prevent the user from editing the txt file outside the program.

Some things to consider:
- I want this solution to be portable (well not multi platform, just on windows but I don't want any security settings that I would have to set manually or extra software dependant)
- The method of prevention does not need to be extreme, I just need it to not be trivial as opening the txt and editing it freely.

What my current plan is:
- I want to mask the data with a cypher that the program has built in at read/write and thus making it difficult to easily edit while maintaining the key.
- I will be doing data validation @ read time to confirm both the cypher key and of course that the data is legit.

My problem:
- The user can open up the txt and change a value to another legit data

What I would like:
- Some mutex like locking functionality that windows api would support that I could code in a portable fashion (within windows platform) that a user could run just as long as they have the visual c++ redistributable. (But I'll take any help)

Thanks for the read, I hope to see some input :)

EDIT:

I was wondering, since zip is supported by windows platforms by default, is there anyway to write to a .zip container which could be encrypted at the creation of the .zip and then accessed in the program with the key? I think this would be an ideal solution if it's doable

Comment: _'Some mutex like locking functionality that windows api would support ...'_ I'm afraid there's no such _magical_ thing available.

Comment: Your only option is based on encryption of some sort. One option (which doesn't make the content unreadable) is to include within the file a digital signature that gets used to verify the content has not changed. The problem though shifts to: where does the signing (or encrypting) key get stored?

Comment: @user3483187: Why do you want to do that? If a user changes the file and break the programs functionality, it´s his own fault.

Comment: hmm I guess theres no magical greatness :( that was initial plan, I was considering the "cypher" or digital signature to be hard coded into the program. I'm not worried about anyone decrypting my signature or anything of the like, I just dont want the editing to be trivial. I appreciate the reassurance that its a decent direction to head. I will most likely do that and then each field read in, if modified will get defaulted and the user notified of the modified dbase. Also this is a school project, so I'd like to make it nice:)

Comment: I was wondering, since zip is supported by windows platforms by default, is there anyway to write to a .zip container which could be encrypted at the creation of the .zip and then accessed in the program with the key? I think this would be an ideal solution if it's doable

Comment: the answer to your question has already been addressed in the second comment.  Also, you need to know that nothing you do on the local machine will ever be secure.  Never.  If you want to store data that the user can not manipulate then you need to store it in your pocket.  Or perhaps a server in a locked room someplace.  You will never secure data remotely.  It is not possible.  You can make it difficult, as people have pointed out, to tamper with data.  But it will never be impossible to outsmart your program.  Encrypt the data, Sign the data, and store the data on a server.

Comment: No zip will not solve this. The password protection on zip is extremely easy to remove.

Comment: I just want to point out, I'm not trying to make the data "safe", I just want it to not be tamper-able in a trivial manor such as just simply opening the txt and editing freely. If they have to go through the trouble of removing the password on the zip, kudos to them.

Comment: If you do not care how easy this is to hack then a password protected zip is an option. Although it would probably be simpler to just encrypt the data.

Comment: This is sort of a "cheesy" way that will not stop everyone. Change the file type exstention.  name it .ful  instead of .txt  or something like that.  mark the file as hidden.  Unless the end user really knows what to look for they would not know that it has a the wrong extention.  Of course this is NOT a secure method, and is not a best practice.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is even possible, so my suggestion is encrypting the data you want to store in the .txt file.

The following is a simple XOR encryption algorithm, if you want to decrypt the data, just run the method again with the encrypted string.

```
std::string crypt(std::string str, char key) { // If you want to, you can apply proper const-ness
    std::string result = str; // Create a result string
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) result[i] = str[i] ^ key; // For every character in the string XOR it with the key
    return result; // Return the result
}
```

i hope this helped you.